# How to add multi nested list in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I would like to create target_groups in a for loops like the below output and `targets` has two nested maps

example output

```
 + out = [
      + {
          + backend_port         = 443
          + backend_protocol     = "TCP"
          + deregistration_delay = 10
          + name_prefix          = "var.name_prefix"
          + preserve_client_ip   = true
          + target_type          = "ip"
          + targets              = {
              +nodes = {
                 + port = 443
               }
            }
        },
    ]
```

This is the variable and simple loop example for my attempts.

```
variable "target_groups" {
  description = "A list of maps describing the HTTP listeners or TCP ports for this NLB"
  type        = any
  default = {
    tg1 = {
      name_prefix          = "test"
      backend_protocol     = "TCP"
      backend_port         = 443
      target_type          = "ip"
      deregistration_delay = 10
      preserve_client_ip   = true
      stickiness = {
        enabled = true
        type    = "source_ip"
      }
      targets = {
        nodes = {
          target_id = "191.11.11.11"
          port      = 443
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

locals

```
locals {
  target_groups = flatten([

      for tg_data in var.target_groups: {
        name_prefix          = "var.name_prefix"
        backend_protocol     = tg_data.backend_protocol
        backend_port         = tg_data.backend_port
        target_type          = tg_data.target_type
        deregistration_delay = tg_data.deregistration_delay
        preserve_client_ip   = tg_data.preserve_client_ip

   
        targets = {
            for k,tg_l in tg_data.targets : 
                "port" => tg_l.port
        }
        // failed nested code
        //targets = {
        //    for k,tg_l in tg_data.targets : 
        //        k => tomap({
        //           "port" => tg_l.port
        //        })
        //}
      }
  ])
}

output "out" {
  description = "Local."
  value       = local.target_groups
}
```

result

```
  out = [
      + {
          + backend_port         = 443
          + backend_protocol     = "TCP"
          + deregistration_delay = 10
          + name_prefix          = "var.name_prefix"
          + preserve_client_ip   = true
          + target_type          = "ip"
          + targets              = {

              + port = 443
            }
        },
    ]
```

Is there a way to put several nested `list` in the for loop?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is what you want:

```
locals {
  target_groups = flatten([

    for tg_data in var.target_groups : {
      name_prefix          = "var.name_prefix"
      backend_protocol     = tg_data.backend_protocol
      backend_port         = tg_data.backend_port
      target_type          = tg_data.target_type
      deregistration_delay = tg_data.deregistration_delay
      preserve_client_ip   = tg_data.preserve_client_ip


      targets = {
        for k, tg_l in tg_data.targets : k => {
          "port" : tg_l.port
        }
      }
    }
  ])
}
```

The output will be:

```
out = [
  {
    "backend_port" = 443
    "backend_protocol" = "TCP"
    "deregistration_delay" = 10
    "name_prefix" = "var.name_prefix"
    "preserve_client_ip" = true
    "target_type" = "ip"
    "targets" = {
      "nodes" = {
        "port" = 443
      }
    }
  },
]
```